# insert mutlitple records using restapi apex

Tags: apex, api, webservices, rest, httppost

I hv 2 salesforce instances & I am inserting multiple account records from source to orgnz. The access token part is working , but I do not understand how to pass multiple account records.
In destination:

```
@HTTPPost  //for inserting multiple accounts
webservice static void InsertMultipleAccounts() 
{
   List<Account> NewAccList=new List<Account>();
   RestRequest req=RestContext.Request;
   RestResponse res=RestContext.Response;
   string req_body=req.RequestBody.ToString();
   if (req_body != NULL)
   {
     NewAccList=(List<Account>)JSON.deserialize(req_body,List<Account>.class);
   }
}
```

**In source:**

```
public PageReference InsertMultipleAccounts()
{
   if (Helper.GetAccessToken() != NULL) //access token
  {
      Http h = new Http();
      HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
      req.setMethod('POST');
      req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+Helper.GetAccessToken().access_token);
      req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json; charset=UTF-8'); 
      req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
     req.setEndpoint('https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/AccountRest');   
     String dataupload = JSON.serialize(a);
      req.setBody(dataupload);
      HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 
  }
return NULL;
}
In source I created a VF page & a controller
<apex:InputTest value={!a.Name}"/>

public class A
{
  public A()
  {
    a = New Account();
   }
}
```

Please let me how to pass multiple account records in json so that I can capture them on destination side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce supports inserting multiple records from the box: [Create Multiple Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm)

You have to translate your accounts to correspondent format. It can be done with custom classes that has all required attributes.

```
public with sharing class restTreeAccount {
    //counter will add reference for new accounts
    private static Integer counter = 1;

    public class TreeAccount{
        public Attr attributes;
        public String Name;

        public TreeAccount(String n){
            this.Name = n;
            this.attributes = new Attr();
        }
    }

    public class Attr{
        public String referenceId;
        public String type;
        public Attr(){
            this.referenceId = 'ref' + String.valueOf(counter++);
            this.type = 'Account';
        }
    }

    public static String generateTreeJson (list<Account> accounts) {
        list<TreeAccount> records = new list <TreeAccount>();

        for (Account acc :accounts ){
            records.add(new TreeAccount(acc.name));
        }   

        return '{\"records\":'+Json.serialize(records)+'}';
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
list <account> accts = new list <account>{new account(name='ilya'),new account(name='lepesh')};
system.debug(restTreeAccount.generatetreeJson(accts));
```

Output:

```
{
    "records": [{
        "Name": "ilya",
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Account",
            "referenceId": "ref1"
        }
    }, {
        "Name": "lepesh",
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Account",
            "referenceId": "ref2"
        }
    }]
}
```

You just can send it from your source instance with POST to

```
https://xxxx.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/composite/tree/Account/
```

Comment: I am getting the JSON format in source and destination. In destination as per my code I am doing this.  NewAccountList=(List<Account>)JSON.deserialize(req_body,List<Account>.class); but I am getting error as Malformed JSON, Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set

Comment: you're sending single record, but expecting list. Try to modify to String dataupload = JSON.serialize(new list <account>{a});

Comment: List<Account> InsertAccList=[select Name from Account where CreatedDate=last_N_Days:1 Order By CreatedDate];
          string jsonList=JSON.Serialize(InsertAccList);